# From FTP to Bitbucket/Dropbox/Box

Tags: php, mysql, backup, bitbucket

On my FTP server I do automatic backups of a MySQL database (one MySQL dump file) when I logout from my CMS. The script is in PHP.

But, on Bitbucket, I don't have an actual version of this file and I want to have a backup when FTP or MySQL shuts down.

How can I download, maybe via cron or in a PHP script, a file to my disk (dropbox, box) or how can I publish via PHP to Bitbucket?

Comment: Git is not a suitable backup mechanism for SQL dumps. It's really more for code, and for things directly connected to code like READMEs, configuration templates, and SQL schemas.

Answer (score 0):

ok, and other mechanism of backup to dropbox or somethink cloud service? Box/Drive etc. ?

Thank you.